# Change order price display incl. tax and excl. tax

Tags: price, magento2.2, catalog, tax

At the moment the price is displayed like this :

> ## **Price incl. Tax**
>
> Price excl. Tax

And I would like to display it like this :

> ## **Price excl. Tax**
>
> Price incl. Tax

In a previous question someone answered that you had to put :

```
<?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
    <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

at line ~15 of module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
(I'm working on a test server, I will override it on the production server)

I tried this and it displayed :

> ## **Price excl. Tax Price incl. Tax**
>
> Price excl. Tax

I'm not sure what getAdjustementsHtml() does and I can't find it in the catalog file.
I'm quite new to Magento and web in general so I'm a bit lost in Magento's architecture.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

EDIT: I succeeded to obtain something okay for now : activate only excl. tax display and override the price display, then get the excl. tax price, multiply it by the tax rate and display this where you want. This works only if all your products have the same tax rate obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can change order by changes in some vendor file and override them by your own demand.

For Cart Page go in module-tax:

path : vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.html

Change `<tr>` order:

```
<tr class="grand totals excl">
<th class="mark" scope="row">
    <strong data-bind="i18n: exclTaxLabel"></strong>
</th>
<td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': exclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
    <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getGrandTotalExclTax()"></span></strong>
</td>
```

[image]

For Checkout Page go in module-tax:

path : /vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html

Change `<tr>` order:

```
<tr class="grand totals excl">
<th class="mark" scope="row">
    <strong data-bind="i18n: exclTaxLabel"></strong>
</th>
<td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': exclTaxLabel}" class="amount">
    <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getGrandTotalExclTax()"></span></strong>
</td>
```

[image]